# Inside Jquery easyui multiple tab submit button click event is redirecting to home (first) tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jquery easyui multiple tabs to show mulitple working screens.Now in a specific tab i have added one submit which needs to save data into the database from the user inputs present in the tab but the problem that i am facing is that on button click event instead of saving data into database it is navigating into the firts tab (Home) screen of the easyui mulitple tab .
Here is the code for the click event to open easyui multiple tab..

```
 <a href="#" style="color:Black" onclick="addTab('Reservation','')">Reservation</a>
```

and here is the 'Reservation' panel ..

```
         <div id="Reservationuserform" class="panel panel-primary" style=" margin:-10px; display:none;margin-left:-16px; margin-top:-15px; margin-right:-16px;">
         <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Reservation</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
          <button type="submit" id="reserve" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Reserve</button>
            <br />
            <br />
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
         <label for="Booking Id">Booking Id</label>
         <input type="BookingId"  id="1" placeholder="Enter Booking Id">
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

and here is the button click event on 'Reservation' tab on clicking which it is going to Home (first) tab of mutlitab window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reserve").click(function () {
        alert("hello");
        var BookingId = $("#1").val();
});
</script>
```

Please help me and point out where i am going wrong as i am not able to find out.Thanks..

Comment: You should create a javascript function which will call addTab and then, return false.

Comment: @Urbane ' <a href="#" style="color:Black" onclick="addTab('Reservation','')">Reservation</a>' In this line i am doing the same thing .Is something missed here ?

Comment: If addTab returns false, nothing wrong that I know of...

Comment: Just noticed you link your click event on #Reserve but your code does not seem to have anything with id="Reserve"...

Comment: @Urbane  <button type="submit" id="reserve" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Reserve</button> Here you can see that button id is `reserve` and the issue is that on click event of this button my tab is redirecting to home page..

Comment: is your button in a <form> with an action="..." set ?

Comment: @Urbane No . It is in div like <button type="submit" id="reserve" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Reserve</button>.You can see it in the second code snippet of my post.

Comment: What about setting type="button" instead of "submit" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
<a href="#" style="color:Black" onclick="addTabReservation();">Reservation</a>
```

With :

```
function addTabReservation()
{
  addTab('Reservation','');
  return false;
}
```